Python + Comtypes app compatibilityt errors
I created a project that used CustomTkinter, Python, Multiprocessing, comtypes, python-docx and more.
The project lets the user enter information of an individual stored in a sqilte database and can generate form from a word file that serves as a template, where python-docx searches the placeholder texts that i placed to replace with actual information of that individual and then comtypes would convert that generated word file into pdf. But it seems that i am facing some inconsistencies, like sometimes and error pops up because of PermissionError or OSError, i dont know what is happening to it. Did i do i bad choice in combining this technologies or are there any better way to do this?
